# Emma compatibility with Java version

Tags: java, jvm, emma

Is Emma code coverage tool compatible with Java 7?

The documentation states:

*According the the paper "EclEmma 2.0", Jacoco (that you looked) is supposed to work with Java 1.7.
(see all Jacoco releases here)
Java Runtime: As JaCoCo requires Java 1.5 the same minimum JRE is required for the Eclipse instance running EclEmma and the application under test.
Note that this does not apply to the Java class files under test: Any class file version ranging from Java 1.0 to 1.7 is possible.
The latest changes history mentions:
Release 0.6.0 (2012/10/06)
New Features
Full support for Java 7 including INVOKEDYNAMIC as JaCoCo is now based on ASM 4.0 (GitHub #5).
(since then, 0.6.1, 2012/12/19 has been released)*

But I couldn't get it running with Java 7? Has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 1):

eclEmma is not supported in Java 7 because it fails with java7 bytecode. [Here](http://www.eclemma.org/devdoc/eclemma20.html) is the eclEmma weblink.

Comment: Thanks! do you have any idea what could be other java code coverage options for offline instrumentation?

Comment: You can use ecobertura eclipse plugin for code coverage. I am currently using it in eclipse kepler and imo it is the best code coverage plugin for eclipse. link :http://ecobertura.johoop.de/

Comment: From its description it seems to be Eclipse plugin. I am looking something which can instrument in the code and check coverage during runtime for integration testing.

Comment: By integration testing if you mean "Running test builds on Jenkins/Hudson or any other integration server" , then you can try Atlassian's Clover.It is a commercial product but they do have a 30 day free trial. Clover integrates with IDE also. https://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/overview